# Overflow issue in a fixed position sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed sidebar, with `overflow-x:hidden` so I get a scrollbar to scroll.  But now I want to add a submenu, that when shown will overflow into the main window.

This works fine if I set `overflow:visible` but then I lose the scrolling ability.

Can I get them both together?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPzvdP

```css
#sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #396DA5;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu ul ul {
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

#menu ul ul {
  padding: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 80%;
  top: 0;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div id=menu>
    <ul>
      <li>Item Hover
        <ul>
          <li>subitem<li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

The top li item has a hover, that can be fully see when the  `overflow-x:hidden` is removed from the top css line, but then the side bar cant be scrolled!

EDIT - Answers have said use `position:fixed` and this works.  But can this be applied to any of the list items so the submenu opens beside the parent?

Answer (score 3):

No need to add `overflow-y`.

Your class should be

```
#menu ul  li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 8px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwEezZ)

Comment: Yes that works thanks but leads to a new question - can the position be relative so it can work for a sub menu any item on the list?  I added item 2 further down the list - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNxyVP

Comment: wow this actually works, thanks!. But what If I need the `overflow-y` property? is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try 
    overflow-y: scroll

and set your hover box to position fixed:

```
#menu ul ul { padding:50px;     position: fixed; left: 200px; top:0; background:#f00;}
```

You will need to adjust the position.

Not a very pretty solution though.