# Fixed positioned div hidden on Safari

Tags: ios, css, safari, css-position

Following a previous question - [Overflow issue in a fixed position sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457487/show-overflow-of-1-element-in-a-fixed-sidebar-of-hidden-overflow) - I have a list of links with a fixed div showing on `li:hover`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNxyVP

This works great on all the windows browsers - Chrome, Firefox, Explorer, Opera, and old windows Safari.  However on the latest edition of Safari (on Mac) and by extension on iOS the fixed div reveal stays in the grandfather fixed div, and doesn't float over the rest of the page. This also happens on android chrome.

Is there a way to have the fixed div float over the page, and not be restricted to the wrapper - on these browsers?

The other factors such as the wrapper div being scrollable (currently through `overflow-x: hidden;`) would also have to be kept/

Answer (score 12):

because you set your sidebar-wrapper 'position:fixed', in Mac's webkit browser, if an fixed element has a fixed overflow:hidden parent, this element will be hidden.

Comment: While not wrong, suggestions for a workaround or something would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```
  please check this
  #sidebar-wrapper {       
    width:200px;    
    background-color:#396DA5;   
    position:fixed; 
    height: 100%;  
                 }

    #menu ul ul {   
    display: none; 
    list-style: none;
    }  
    #menu ul  li:hover > ul
    {       
     display: block;    
    }
    #menu ul ul { 
    padding:50px;   
    position: absolute; 
    left: 150px;  
    background:#f00; 
    margin-top:-20px;
    }
```

Comment: The sidebar wrapper needs to be scrollable as in the original question.  It would need to show the fixed div with all the other factors being the same.  Thanks