# Fixed/fluid divs with overflow issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I understand that a fixed column can have overflow on X and Y axis'. I also read somewhere that if you set one of the axis' as auto/scroll, the other set will inherit the behavior of the previous one unless it was set to `hidden`.

My dilemma is this: I have a fixed column

```
<div>
    <div class="fixed">
        fixed on the left
    </div>
    <div class="relative">
        scrolls and normal behavior on the right
    </div>
</div>
```

The `fixed` area has a bunch of directives inside of them with their own behavior.

Some of the directives have `ng-show`s that enable a pop-up that has pertinent data and information that needs to keep getting passed back and forth.

When the pop-up appears, it is nested inside of the fixed div and is part of `scroll-x` which is set to `overflow: hidden` because otherwise the div scrolls left-to-right and the behavior is broken.

This is my expected behavior:

[image]

This is the actual behavior:

[image]

Anyone know how I can achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the little popup to be on top of everything? Try using z-index.

Comment: as Lansana said try using z-index, or try removing the overflow-hidden part on just the popup

Comment: No amount of z-index will help you if you have an element inside another that has `overflow:hidden` property. You need to remove the overflowing if you want it to go out of the div.

Comment: As @dingo_d mentioned, z-index doesn't help the case as the width of the fixed box is X and the popup is X + Y wide. @dingo_d, I don't want the div to scroll, and if I remove `overflow:hidden` it takes the behavior of the other `overflow` axis and will begin to scroll.

Comment: You can still make `overflow-y: hidden;`, so the scroll shouldn't happen.

Comment: Yeah, but then it hides the rest of the content.

Comment: Check out this post see if it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/q/28457487/483779

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by compiling and injecting the directive outside of the fixed div area.

Compiling inside the directive that was previously generating all the data/code for the pop-up that I needed to display outside of the fixed area was what solved it.

On build of the directive I'm compiling a second directive with the current directives scope (which was needed) being passed through.

Thank you for your help and if someone runs into this issue, let me know and I'll be happy to share the code.